# Multiline select options overflow vertical slider arrow

Tags: html, css, multiple-select

I am using multiline select element in my web app to display options. Some options might be long enough, thus they are hidden if they are longer then the select width.
The problem is that there are cases when one of the options is long enough and is hidden under the vertical slider arrow. In those cases if you press arrow(down or up) the arrow is not pressed, but the option is selected.
Here is a libe example of what I mean:    https://jsfiddle.net/nitoloz/j29d3emm/1/` 
(try to scroll down using arrow button in the vertical slider)

I hope this could be fixed with either some css tricks(z-index or smth similar), but I can not find a solution

Comment: You have to use position property to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to used `position` property please check below code

```
select{
      position: relative;
}
select option{
      position: static;
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j29d3emm/7/)

Comment: That works and is exactly what I need!
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put `white-space: normal;` to option elements. That way if the option is too long it just goes into another line instead of being under the scroller.

Updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/j29d3emm/6/

Comment: Thank you!
This seems to be a nice solution, however I would prefer somehow remain all the options single line(I have horizontal slider for this purpose).
Moreover such approach might increase select height unexprectidly

Answer (score -1):

You can just replace the `width: 100%` to `width: auto` on the class `.form-control`

DEMO :

https://jsfiddle.net/j29d3emm/2/

Comment: this way form gets outside of its parent div .col-md-3

Comment: Thanks!
Unfortunately i have my select in a side panel and it should not overflow the parent div

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I did not pay attention to it